# check box if select one un-select all other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Ok, so i have a list of check boxes 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. I would like the function to select 2, 3, 4 and 5 but if 1 is selected then un-select 2, 3, 4 and 5, once 2 to 5 are un-selected display a message in a div.

So far I can select 1 and one of the others... and the message comes on selection of 1

**problem 1**
I cant un-select 2 to 5 once 1 is selected

**problem 2**
The message is displayed on page load even if the box is un-selected.

**HTML**

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="" value="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" id="boxchecked"  />
one <br/>

<input type="checkbox" class="check" />
two <br/>

<input type="checkbox" class="check" />
three <br/>

<input type="checkbox" class="check" />
four <br/>

<input type="checkbox" class="check" />
five

<div id="hidden">Two to five can not be selected whilst you have one selected</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('input.check').on('change', function() {
    $('input.check').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#boxchecked").click(function ()
  {
      if ($("#boxchecked").is(':checked'))
      {
          $("#hidden").show();
      }
      else
      {
          $("#hidden").hide();
      }              
  });
});

$('input[name=CheckboxGroup1]').attr('checked', false);
```

Comment: What if I select `1` and then select `2`?

Comment: You have to use `radio` instead of `checkbox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I propose. How about giving the checkbox that can only be singly checked a class, and the others another class?
Hope it helps.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('singlecheck')) {
       if($('input.multicheck').is(":checked")) {
         $('#warning').show();  
       }
       $('input.multicheck').prop('checked', false);
    } else {
      $('input.singlecheck').prop('checked', false);
      $('#warning').hide();
    }
     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="singlecheck" value="one" name="CheckboxGroup1" id="boxchecked"  />
one <br/>

<input type="checkbox" class="multicheck" value="two"/>
two <br/>

<input type="checkbox" class="multicheck" value="three"/>
three <br/>

<input type="checkbox" class="multicheck" value="four"/>
four <br/>

<input type="checkbox" class="multicheck" value="five"/>
five

<div id="warning" style="display:none">Two to five can not be selected whilst you have one selected</div>
```

Comment: This one is perfect out of all the answers it gives the functionality i needed. thank you.

Comment: You can change `if($(this).attr("class") == 'singlecheck') ` to `if($(this).hasClass('singlecheck'))`

Comment: if you have multiple classes, it will fail. It would look like `"singlecheck test" == "singlecheck"`

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks for the comment. Still a newb in jquery, always learning. :P Updated the answer.

Comment: @Rajesh Well, instead of class then he could use the id of the first checkbox or some other attribute instead.

Comment: @coffeeak Yes.We should. Also its alriight. We learn from our mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

To un-select check box 2-5, you can use something like this:

```
$('input[name="CheckboxGroup1"]').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('input.check').prop('checked', false);
  }
})
```

For message to be hidden initially, you can have an initialization function that will set/reset UI states to default

```
function initUI() {
  $('input[name=CheckboxGroup1]').attr('checked', false);
  $('#hidden').hide();
}
```

[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qfe0fwn4/)

Also, for cases where you have `if...else` to toggle visibility of a field, you should use `.toggle(VisibilityValue)`

```
$("#boxchecked").click(function() {
  $("#hidden").toggle($("#boxchecked").is(':checked'))
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qfe0fwn4/1/)

Comment: Hmm almost, except i need the function that you can select 2 to 5 at the same time but not when 1 is selected

Comment: @Beep You can check following [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qfe0fwn4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is that you can disable the checkboxes 2-5 as soon as the checkbox 1 is checked and then show the message. If one is not checked your can enable the other checkboxes and hide the message as:

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){

  if($('#boxchecked').prop('checked')) {
    $('.check').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#hidden').show();
  }
  else {
    $('.check').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#hidden').hide();
  }
  
})
```

```css
#hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="" value="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" id="boxchecked"  />
one <br/>

<input type="checkbox" class="check" />
two <br/>

<input type="checkbox" class="check" />
three <br/>

<input type="checkbox" class="check" />
four <br/>

<input type="checkbox" class="check" />
five

<div id="hidden">Two to five can not be selected whilst you have one selected</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**i think you want this type fuctionality** **:**

**jQuery**

```
var box = null;

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".check").click(function() {


        box = this.id;

        $(".check").each(function() {
            if ( this.id == box )
            {
                this.checked = true;
                //$("#hidden").show();
                var cval =$(this).val();
                document.getElementById("get").innerHTML =cval;
            }
            else
            {
                this.checked = false;

            };        
        });
    });    
});
```

**HTml Code**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="one" name="CheckboxGroup1" id="one"  />
one <br/>

<input type="checkbox" class="check" id="two" value="two"   />
two <br/>

<input type="checkbox" class="check" id="three" value="three"   />
three <br/>

<input type="checkbox" class="check"  id="four" value="four"  />
four <br/>

<input type="checkbox" class="check" id="five" value="five"  />
five

<div id="hidden">This checkbox number is <label id="get">0</label></div>
```

**I hope its usefull for you**